# Apple Watch App Image Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-watch

I have just downloaded `Xcode 6.2` (Beta) and tried my first app on `Apple Watch`. I have tested the app successfully by putting a simple static label and ran the app perfectly. However, when I am trying to put an `Image` control on the `Interface Controller`, it shows up onn the storyboard but not when the app is launched in the `Apple Watch Simulator`.
Here is what storyboard shows

[image]

But this is what happens when I run the app

[image]

I am not an expert not even intermediate level iPhone developer but just a learner, so may be I am missing some thing basic.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select the image file in XCode
- Open Utilities View in XCode (The right most icon in the screenshot below)

[image]

- Select you watch app target check box under "Target Membership"
  heading.

Comment: Tip: If you are importing images in the future, just be sure to check the Apple Watch as the target as well. Otherwise you will have to do what @msk suggested for every single image you use.